# Transgression maps in group cohomology and group homology / duality of spectral sequences 

Tags: group-cohomology, group-homology, spectral-sequences

I am interested in whether the transgression maps for group cohomology and group homology are related via a version of the universal coefficient theorem.

Let $G$ be a group, $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$ and let $A$ and $B$ finite rank free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules equipped with actions of $G$ and a $G$-equivariant perfect pairing

$$A \times B \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}.$$

The Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequences in cohomology and homology give transgression maps:

$$d^2 : \operatorname{H}^1(H,B \otimes \mathbb{C}^{\times})^{G/H} \rightarrow \operatorname{H}^2(G/H, (B \otimes \mathbb{C}^{\times})^H),$$

$$d_2 : \operatorname{H}_2(G/H, A_H) \rightarrow \operatorname{H}_1(H, A)_{G/H}.$$

Assume that $H$ acts trivially on $A$ and $B$, and suppose that the order of $G/H$ is $m < \infty$.

Since $H$ acts trivially on $B$, the universal coefficients theorem gives a map

$$\operatorname{H}^1(H,B \otimes \mathbb{C}^{\times}) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{H}_1(H, \mathbb{Z}), B \otimes \mathbb{C}^{\times}).$$

Since $A$ is torsion-free, $B \otimes \mathbb{C}^{\times} = \operatorname{Hom}(A, \mathbb{C}^{\times})$, so 
$$\operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{H}_1(H,\mathbb{Z}),B \otimes \mathbb{C}^{\times})^{G/H} = \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{H}_1(H,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes A, \mathbb{C}^{\times})^{G/H} $$ $$= \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{H}_1(H, A), \mathbb{C}^{\times})^{G/H} = \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{H}_1(H,A)_{G/H}, \mathbb{C}^{\times}).$$

We thus get an isomorphism between the domain of $d^2$ and dual of the codomain of $d_2$.  We can't use the universal coefficient theorem for the other pair since $G/H$ may not act trivially, but we can replace it as follows.  Tate-Nakayama duality says that cup product induces a perfect pairing 
$$\hat{\operatorname{H}}^n(G/H, A) \times \hat{\operatorname{H}}^{-n}(G/H, B) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} / m \mathbb{Z},$$
where $\hat{\operatorname{H}}$ denotes Tate cohomology.

Via the exponential sequence 
$$0 \rightarrow B \rightarrow B \otimes \mathbb{C} \rightarrow B \otimes \mathbb{C}^{\times} \rightarrow 0$$
one obtains an isomorphism

$$\operatorname{H}^2(G/H, (B \otimes \mathbb{C}^{\times})^H) = \operatorname{H}^2(G/H, B \otimes \mathbb{C}^{\times}) = \operatorname{H}^3(G/H, B).$$

Following this isomorphism by Tate-Nakayama duality, we finally get a partial diagram

\begin{array}{cccc}
 \operatorname{H}^1(H,B \otimes \mathbb{C}^{\times})^{G/H} &\xrightarrow{d^2}&\operatorname{H}^2(G/H, B \otimes \mathbb{C}^{\times}) \\
 \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
 \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{H}_1(H,A)_{G/H},\mathbb{C}^{\times}) & & \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{H}_2(G/H,A),\mathbb{C}^{\times})
\end{array}

**Does adding**
$$d_2^{\vee} : \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{H}_1(H,A)_{G/H}, \mathbb{C}^{\times}) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(\operatorname{H}_2(G/H, A_H), \mathbb{C}^{\times})$$ **make the diagram commute?  Does anyone know a reference for such a statement?**

Comment: I don't really see how to define the vertical maps in your diagram, unless you assume that $A$ is trivial as a $G$-module?

Comment: Dear Mark, thank you for your comment, you are absolutely right.  I have edited the question to include the assumption that $G$ acts trivially on $A$.

Comment: The codomain of $F$ is (trivial coefficients) $\operatorname{Hom}(H_2(G/H;\mathbb{Z}),A)$ while the codomain of $d_2^{\vee}$ is $\operatorname{Hom}(H_2(G/H,A^\vee), \mathbb{C}^{\times})$. So when you ask if $F=d_2^\vee$, does this mean $A=\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ and $A^\vee = \mathbb{Z}$ ? 

Comment: Dear Ralph : note that $Hom(H_2(G/H,A^{\vee}), \mathbb{C}^{\times}) = Hom(H_2(G/H,\mathbb{Z}) \otimes A^{\vee}, \mathbb{C}^{\times})$, which by adjointness of $Hom$ and $\otimes$, equals $Hom(H_2(G/H, \mathbb{Z}), Hom(A^{\vee}, \mathbb{C}^{\times})) = Hom(H_2(G/H, \mathbb{Z}), A)$.  This is all because $A$ is assumed to be torsion-free, implying that $H_2(G/H, A^{\vee}) = H_2(G/H, \mathbb{Z}) \otimes A^{\vee}$  (similar for $H_1$).

Comment: It seems that Ralph's answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/94424/how-to-compute-transgressions-in-a-serre-spectral-sequence should be useful in obtaining a general statement. In fact, all that is missing is the precise relationship between the homology transgression $H_2(G/H;A)\to H_1(H;A)_{G/H}$ and the class in $H^2(G/H;H_1(H))$ which classifies the extension $H_1(H)\to G/H'\to G/H$.

Comment: Dear Mark: Thank you very much for your comment...I have actually already seen Ralph's answer on this.  As you say, however, more is needed, and I am hoping that someone knows of a good reference for the rest of what I am seeking.  It might be possible that one could prove the commutativity of the diagram by chasing (co)cycles and using the underlying spectral sequences, but I was really hoping to avoid this.

Comment: In your 2nd comment it seems that you assume $A\cong Hom(A^\vee,\mathbb{C}^\times)=A^{\vee\vee}$. But for example $\mathbb{Z}^{\vee\vee}=Hom(\mathbb{C}^\times,\mathbb{C}^\times)$ is uncountable. Also I don't understand why $A$ torsionfree implies $H_2(G/H,A^\vee)\cong H_2(G/H,\mathbb{Z})\otimes A^\vee$. Note that $\mathbb{Z}^\vee = \mathbb{C}^\times$ has torsion and isn't a flat $\mathbb{Z}$-module. So there is an abelian group $G$ with $Tor(G,\mathbb{Z}^\vee)\neq 0$ and thus, by UCT, $H_2(G,\mathbb{Z}^\vee)\neq H_2(G,\mathbb{Z})\otimes \mathbb{Z}^\vee$.  

Comment: ... I wonder if you are assuming some topology and continuous (co)homology ? Anyway, there 
is some duality between $E_r$ and $E^r$ that can be established after the coefficient issue has been clarified. 

Comment: @Moshe: How is $F$ in the commutative diagram defined ? 

Comment: Dear Ralph : I have been very sloppy. I need to give more information about the categories that I am working in.  In particular, I am thinking of $Hom$ as algebraic homomorphisms, so $Hom(\mathbb{C}^{\times}, \mathbb{C}^{\times}) = \mathbb{Z}$.  Also, I should have assumed that $A^{\vee}$ is torsion-free, not $A$ is torsion free, because what I needed was $H_2(G/H, A^{\vee}) = H_2(G/H, \mathbb{Z}) \otimes A^{\vee}$, as you wrote.  Also, I am definitely assuming some topology and continuous (co)homology.  I am interested in some duality between $E_r$ and $E^r$, as you say.

Comment: But to be honest, I might actually need to rewrite parts of this question.  I will do this as soon as possible, hopefully later today.

Comment: Dear Ralph, Demin, Mark : I have rewrote the whole question for the special case that I need.  I originally thought that I could generalize my question enough so that a wider audience would be interested, but I realize that I cannot, as far as I can currently tell.  My apologies for the earlier sloppiness.  Also: Ralph, I would be interested to know of any references about duality between $E_r$ and $E^r$, as well as your thoughts on the reformulation of my question.

Comment: The question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34754/are-the-homology-and-cohomology-serre-spectral-sequences-dual-to-each-other may be relevant here. Note that the LHSS is a special case of the Serre spectral sequence ( where base, total and fibre space are aspherical).

Comment: Dear Mark : Thank you very much for the link, at a first glance it looks relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your update and hope the late answer is still of help. Remarks: (1) The question looks much better now. (2) You write $d^2: H^1 \to H^2$ and $d_2: H_2 \to H_1$. But the correct/usual notation for the differential in the SS is here $d^2: H_2 \to H_1,\;d_2: H^1 \to H^2$. (3) The presentation simplifies if you drop $B$ and just use $A^\ast :=Hom(A,\mathbb{C})$ in place of $B\otimes \mathbb{C}$. (4) As shown in my answer, the diagram in question commutes. Restrictions like trivial $H$-action on $A$ or $(G:H)< \infty$ aren't needed.  


Comment: I mean $A^\ast = Hom(A,\mathbb{C}^\times)$ in (3).   

Comment: Dear Ralph : Thank you very much for your response, I will mull it over within the next few days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have the following general result:

> **Lemma:** Let $K$ be a filtered complex of ablian groups and let $I$ be an ablian group. Filter the cocomplex $K^\ast := \text{Hom}(K,I)$ by the dual filtration (def. in proof). Then there is a homomorphism $\phi_r: E_r(K^\ast) \to E^r(K)^\ast$ of abelian groups such that the following diagram commutes: 
>   $$\begin{array}{ccc}
> E_r^{ij} & \xrightarrow{d_r} & E_r^{i+r,j-r+1} \newline 
> {\scriptstyle\phi_r}\downarrow\;\; & & \;\;\downarrow{\scriptstyle\phi_r} \newline
> (E^r_{ij})^\ast & \xrightarrow[(d^r)^\ast]{} & (E^r_{i+r,j-r+1})^\ast
> \end{array}$$ 
>   If $I$ is injective, then $(\phi_r)_{r\ge 0}$ is an isomorphism of spectral sequences.

As a corollary we obtain:

> Let $A$ be a $G$-modules, $I$ an injective abelian group (with trivial $G$-action), and denote the homology LHS spectral sequence with coefficients in $A$ by $E^r(A)$ (and respectively for cohomology). Then there is an isomorphism $\phi_r: E_r(A^\ast) \to E^r(A)^\ast$ of spectral sequences.

*Proof:* Let $P$ resp. $Q$ be projective resolutions of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $G$ resp. $G/H$ and put $X=Q \otimes P$. Then the cohomology LHS spectral sequence is the spectral sequence of of the filtration of the cocomplex
$$\text{Hom}_G(X,A^\ast)=\text{Hom}_G(X,\text{Hom}(A,I))\cong \text{Hom}_G(X\otimes A,I) \cong \text{Hom}(X\otimes_GA,I)$$
(the last iso needs $I$ to be trivial) and the homology LHS spectral sequence is the spectral sequence of the filtration of $X\otimes_G A$. Now the results follows from the lemma. qed.

**Remark:** If $I$ is injective, then the lemma can be proved easier by using exact couples (in the same manner as in Tyler Lawson's answer to the question linked by Mark Grant). But if there are additional structures in the spectral sequences like products, Steenrod power operations, etc. that one wants to compare, then it's helpful to have an explicit map $\phi_r$ as defined below. For example, this way one can show that $\phi_2^{2,0}: H^2(G/H,(A^\ast)^H)\to H_2(G/H,A_H)^\ast$ is induced by $$\text{Hom}_{G/H}(Q_2,(A^\ast)^H) \to (Q_2 \otimes_{G/H}A_H)^\ast,\; f \mapsto (x \otimes \bar{a} \mapsto f(x)(a)).$$

**Proof of the lemma:** Let $C := K^\ast$ with differential $\delta = d^\ast$. The dual filtration is defined by $F^rC^i=\lbrace f \in \text{Hom}(K_i,I)\mid f|F_{r-1}K_i=0\rbrace$. As usual set 
$$Z^r_{ij}=\lbrace x \in F_iK_{i+j}\mid dx \in F_{i-r}K_{i+j-1}\rbrace\;,\quad 
B^r_{ij}=dZ_{i+r-1,j-r+2}^{r-1}+Z^{r-1}_{i-1,j+1}$$

$$Z_r^{ij}=\lbrace f \in F^iC^{i+j}\mid \delta f \in F^{i+r}C^{i+j+1}\;,\quad 
B_r^{ij}=\delta Z_{r-1}^{i-r+1,j+r-2}+Z^{i+1,j-1}_{r-1}$$
It's straightforward to show that $Z_r^{ij} \to \text{Hom}(Z^r_{ij},I),\;f \mapsto f|Z^r_{ij}$ induces a hom. 
$$\phi_r: E_r^{ij}=Z_r^{ij}/B_r^{ij} \to \text{Hom}(Z^r_{ij}/B^r_{ij},I)=(E^r_{ij})^\ast$$
that makes the diagram in the lemma commute.

Now suppose $I$ is injective. We want to show that $\phi_r$ is bijective. In case $r=0$, $E^0_{ij}=F_iK_{i+j}/F_{i-1}K_{i+j}, E_0^{ij}=F^iC^{i+j}/F^{i+1}C^{i+j}$ and bijectivity is easy to establish. Assume $\phi_r$ is bijective. Then, by the diagram above, $H(\phi_r)$ is bijective and the bijectivity of $\phi_{r+1}$ follows from the commutativity of the diagram below:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
E_{r+1}^{ij} &  \xrightarrow{} & \xrightarrow[\alpha]{\sim} &  H(E_r^{ij}) \newline 
{\scriptstyle\phi_{r+1}}\downarrow\;\; & & & {\scriptstyle\cong}\downarrow {\scriptstyle H(\phi_r)} \newline 
(E_{ij}^{r+1})^\ast & \xleftarrow[\beta^\ast]{\sim} H(E^r_{ij})^\ast & \xleftarrow[\gamma]{\sim} & H( (E^r_{ij})^\ast)
\end{array}$$
Here $\alpha$ is induced by $F_{r+1}^{ij}\hookrightarrow F_r^{ij}$, $\beta$ by $F_{ij}^{r+1}\hookrightarrow F^r_{ij}$ and $\gamma$ (which reflects the fact that the ,exact functor $\text{Hom}(-,I)$ commutes with homology) is given by $\bar{f} +\text{im}\ d_r \mapsto (\bar{x} + \text{im}\; d^r \mapsto f(x)\;)$. qed.